# how to access json within http trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**How do I get the `subject` property from the payload below ?**

I've got an http-triggered logic app:

[image]

I want to be able to grab the contents of the `subject` property.

The schema as shown above in the image looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "topic": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "subject": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "eventType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "eventTime": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "api": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "clientRequestId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "requestId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "eTag": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contentType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contentLength": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "blobType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "sequencer": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "storageDiagnostics": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "batchId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "dataVersion": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "metadataVersion": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "topic",
            "subject",
            "eventType",
            "eventTime",
            "id",
            "data",
            "dataVersion",
            "metadataVersion"
        ]
    }
}
```

**How do I get the `subject` property from this payload?**

Comment: Usually, it works just fine with just using the dynamic content generated by your schema to select the `subject`. Sometimes it is, however, necessary to use a Parse JSON action before you can use dynamic content. I have had this happen to me while working on a 'custom logic app' created for a SOAP on-premise application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your logic app designer in the azure portal and you can specifically assign the json to variables in your flow process

[image: Grabbing the json information]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations) is the link on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

With the Request trigger, if you want to get the property, you need pass the Request Body into json cause the `triggerBody()` value is in a String type, it doesn't support select the property. Set the parse json action like the below pic.

[image]

Then your json set the data in array type, that's another problem you will encounter. So when you select property you need add the index like the below with `Expression`: `body('Parse_JSON')[0]['subject']`.

[image]

I test with short json two properties subject and topic.

[image]